# Custom rules to validate Springboot configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, jax-rs

In my Springboot program, I would like to validate my configuration.

Let's say I have a configuration such as:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("jms")
public class JmsConfiguration {

  protected String brokerType = "";
  protected String host = "";
  protected String port = "";

}
```

I know I can use `@Validated` annotations for very basic checks, e.g.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("jms")
@Validated
public class JmsConfiguration {

  protected String brokerType = "";
  protected String host = "";

  @Positive
  protected String port = ""; /// must be strictly positive

}
```

But how can I make more complex checks? For example, how can I ensure that `brokerType` is whether `ems` or `amq` but nothing else?

Or even more complex, how can I ensure that the port is greater than 1000 if, and only if `brokerType` is `amq` (stupid case but it is for the example)

I tried to use `@Constraint` but I did not succeed (however, I am not sure this is the best way to do what I want...)

Thanks to help

Regards,
Philippe

Answer (score 0):

The `brokerType` can be validated to be either `ems` or `amq` by creating a `enum` for it.

The Spring `@ConfigurationProperties` has first class support for enum.

Please see example here
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/configuration-properties-vs-value-conversion.html

Relevant example From above link

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class MyAppProperties {
  private int refreshRate;
  private TimeUnit refreshTimeUnit;
  private Currency tradeCurrency;
    .............
}
```